# Не приходит +2 при редактировании сообщения

Tags: поддержка, правки, репутация

У меня теперь не приходит +2 при редактировании сообщения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что произошло?

PS: Есть предположение: я уже заработал эту привилегию на другом [сайте](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/users/586/nchistov).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> за принятую предложенную вами правку: +2 (всего до +1000 на одного участника);

Comment: В дополнение, в [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12813/Рейтинг-понижается-до-1999/12814?noredirect=1#comment55688_12814) *αλεχολυτ* подсказал [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/reputation), по ней в самом конце можно посмотреть общее число рейтинга за правки.