# Рейтинг понижается до 1999

Tags: поддержка, репутация, предлагаемые-правки, привилегии

Несколько дней назад получил 2003 и соответствующую привилегию, редактирование без одобрения. Хотя, как по мне, получать +2 рейтинга за одобренное редактирование тоже неплохая привилегия.
Вообще, странно давать такую привилегию по достижении 2000, человек может не редактировать ничего, и получить привилегию, в ранние года можно было задать супер популярный банальный вопрос и получить привилегию, и прочие варианты. Гораздо более осмысленно было бы давать привилегию по достижении определённого количества правок, подробнее писал об этом [здесь](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424406/allow-2000-rep-users-to-bypass-the-queue-limit-when-suggesting-edits-in-review).

Но сейчас не об этом.
Зашёл на ресурс на следующий день, рейтинг 1999. Ладно, вроде бы ничего страшного, скорее всего какие-то отредактированные вопросы / ответы были удалены. Что произошло посмотреть негде. Отредактировал вопрос, получил +2 и рейтинг 2001 соответственно. Захожу на следующий день, опять 1999.

Есть ощущение, что выше 2000 нельзя подняться на редактировании, но об этом нигде не говорится. Собственно, это баг или фича? Если баг, будет смысл на SE ветку открыть.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Совпадение. А в профиле всё есть (а если [ваша репутация больше 10.000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), то даже со ссылками на удалённые вопросы):

[image: скриншот]

> Я так полагаю, вы как модератор можете это смотреть, потому что у меня иначе всё.

Надо просто включить отображение снятий репутации из-за удаления сообщений внизу страницы:

[image: скриншот чекбокса]

До достижения 10000 репутации записи всё равно показываются, но без ссылок:

[image: скриншот удалённого сообщения без ссылки]

Comment: Я так полагаю, вы как модератор можете это смотреть, потому что у меня [иначе всё](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNSY.png). Но, спасибо, по крайней мере понятно, что это не баг. А вот то, что нельзя смотреть понижение рейтинга самостоятельно — довольно странно.

Comment: @DiMithras еще вот такая [страничка есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ интересно, не знал о такой. Но опять же, в ней [минус за удалённый вопрос конкретно мне не видно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBllv.png).

Comment: @DiMithras, ты чекбокс не отметил. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @DiMithras, эти ссылки появляются только после [10.000 репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @Bharatha на вкладке собственной репутации этот чекбокс есть всегда.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, при чём здесь чекбокс?! Независимо от этого чекбокса ссылки будут появляться только после 10.000 репутации. И именно это я написал. Внимательно читайте!

Comment: @Bharatha, почему? До 10000 нельзя просматривать чужие удалённые сообщения, т. е. по ссылке будет 404, но это же страница изменения репутации и почему бы на ней не показываться уменьшению репутации из-за удаления? Тем более, если для этого внизу специальный флажок?

Comment: @Bharatha, ну да, ссылок нет, но записи всё равно есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Да, записи есть, но ведь я нигде не утверждал обратное! Я писал только про ссылки. Однако есть здесь также и ошибка в случае, если пользователь был удалён, то показывается только сообщение о том, что пользователь был удалён, но нет ни названия удалённого сообщения ни тем более ссылки на него. Я считаю, что эта ошибка должна быть исправлена.

Comment: @Bharatha потому что исходная проблема ТС именно чекбоксом решается и не зависит от привилегии 10К. Ссылка - понятие растяжимое, заголовок вопроса - это тоже своего рода ссылка, хоть и не кликабельная.

Comment: @Bharatha, это даже модераторам не показывается...

Comment: @Bharatha про ссылки и удалённого пользователя интересно, спасибо. Но, как верно заметили выше, вопрос в моём случае решался чекбоксом, о существовании которого я не подозревал.